# Is it possible to read a ply format file using python code in Blender

Tags: python

I have a ply file .I need to read the vertices, edges etc. It would be nice to read the ply file in blender and I can program further.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and this applies to most/all other formats.

You can:

- Call the operator from Python:
  `bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath="/path/to.ply")`
- Import the addon module and run the function which is used for importing:
  See the [source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_mesh_ply/import_ply.py;fe34f82e7059bb6b89dfc88b55f030111f2d431f$372), its not to hard to see how you would call the load function. eg:

  ```
  from io_mesh_ply import import_ply
  import_ply.load_ply("/path/to.ply")
  ```

Comment: I have an active object in ply format in blender. I need to read ply data of selected surface in mesh. Can you help me with example code. For example I I need the x,y,z coordinates of the selected portion in the ply mesh. .how can I code to get those details.

Comment: Please help @ideasman42

Comment: @kpdkps, please as a question which goes into some detail about whats needed

Comment: I have ply format mesh in edit mode in blender. When I select some vertices , I need the x y z coordinates to be printed as output. Is it possible. @ideasman42

Comment: @kpdkps, yes, but better ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else lands here from google looking for the answer, in blender 4.0 they [removed the old ply loader implementation](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Import_Export), now it is called through [wm](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html):

```py
bpy.ops.wm.ply_import(filepath="/path/to.ply")
```

On the up side, as it is now implemented in C++, it is much faster (also same applies for obj files).